# How does Telegram Web manage to hide the URLs of the stickers?

Tags: javascript, blob, telegram, telegram-bot

I am planning to integrate Telegram sticker API in my website.

I can successfully fetch the sticker set data and download the sticker image files with the bot API.

I know that it is not secure to use the original Telegram sticker URLs on client side as the URL could expose my bot token, so I may need to make a proxy service to serve the sticker image files.

But the proxy service could be abused by others.

I looked into Telegram Web developer console, I see the website is using Blob URLs (`blob:`) for the images' `src`, but I don't see any image request to the actual server in the "Network" tab, the image requests are also in `blob:` protocol.

I have experienced in using `blob:` URL too. `video.js` turns my source URL into `blob:` URL in the `video` tag, but the browser would still make a request to the actual URL to the server.

But how does Telegram Web do that?

Comment: It's done by MTProto, just fetch data and save to local "blob:" node

Comment: @Sean, can you elaborate? Does Telegram Web use MTProto in the browser instead of HTTP?

Comment: It has HTTP Proxy for MTProto

Comment: So does MTProto make Telegram Web possible to fetch images with Telegram API without exposing the actual URLs in the network requests list?

Comment: It use client API, you already login